# Is Whitehead lemma true for super Lie algebras?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, superalgebra, lie-superalgebras

Classical Whitehead lemma states that if $\mathfrak g$ is a finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra and $M$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak g$-module, then first cohomology group $H^1(\mathfrak g, M)$ (defined for example as cohomology of the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex) is trivial. I need to know if this is also true for super Lie algebras.

Comment: Did you try reading the proof of the lemma and checking if anything breaks down?

Comment: Dear Pedro, I looked at it briefly. The problem is that it uses other properties of Lie algebras for which I also don't know if they generalize to graded case. It will be a great exercise to go through all of that, but this will take time. I hope someone can answer before that. Actually I will also appreciate any references on cohomology of super Lie algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Whitehead Lemmas no longer hold for simple Lie superalgebras.

Reference: [Representations of algebraic groups, quantum groups and Lie algebras](https://books.google.at/books?id=8aMbCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=Whitehead+lemma+for+Lie+superalgebras&source=bl&ots=mq9H6TCOsK&sig=MFKiORLg_ctewORowLmzKgL7GRg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibuYLFw_bcAhUHZFAKHYzbB4s4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=Whitehead%20lemma%20for%20Lie%20superalgebras&f=false), page $121$.

Comment: Technically this answers my question, so I will accept your answer eventually. May I first ask if you are aware of some special class of super Lie algebras for which the first whitehead lemma is true?

Comment: Concerning references for cohomology of Lie superalgebras, see the paper by [Scheunert](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9701037), and the references given there.